# Viewing a city's coordinates from above

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

As a little project I've been thinking to create a little Google Earth-like animation. I want to play back a timeline while rotating the globe to center over various cities. At present I can use the default view settings to render a globe with the cities indicated by points.

[image]

When I try to orient the camera with a view vector looking down on a city (for example Denver), I end up with the following:

[image]

The ViewVector needs to be computed for some point out in space above the globe. However my trial and error has not arrived on any sort of coherent viewpoint with most looking like they're "inside" the globe.

What I need help with is a function which given the latitude and longitude of a city choses a ViewVector placing the city at the "center" of the camera view. The code which produced the "inside the globe" view follows:

```
SC[{lat_, lon_}] := {Cos[lon \[Degree]] Cos[lat \[Degree]], 
   Sin[lon  \[Degree]] Cos[lat  \[Degree]], Sin[lat \[Degree]]};

Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.75],
  Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.99 ],
  Map[Line[
 Map[SC,
  CountryData[#, "SchematicCoordinates"], {-2}]] &,
   CountryData["Countries"]], {Yellow, PointSize[Medium],
   Point[SC[CityData["Denver", "Coordinates"]]]
   }
  },
 Boxed -> False,
 SphericalRegion -> True,
 ViewVector -> {{0, 0, 0}, SC[CityData["Denver", "Coordinates"]]}
 ]
```

Comment: Reminds me of a video a colleague made: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-4y0e1Jdcs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using `ViewVector` in the form `ViewVector->{v1, v2}`, the camera is sitting in point `v1` and is pointed in the direction of `v2`. So in your example, the camera would be sitting in the origin and is pointed in the direction of Denver, which produces the "inside globe" view. To have the camera looking down at Denver the camera should be sitting in a point directly above the city, e.g. in `2 SC[CityData["Denver", "Coordinates"]`  and be pointed at the origin, so `ViewVector` would be something like

```
ViewVector -> {2 SC[CityData["Denver", "Coordinates"]], {0, 0, 0}}
```

With this setting for `ViewVector` the view becomes something like

[image]