# ViewVector transition between two spherical coordinates on a globe

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Continuing with the project I [previously described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645936/viewing-a-citys-coordinates-from-above) I am currently building an animation showing movement between a list of cities. My current code renders a list of cities and makes a set of great circle arcs connecting the cities. The list of cities are part of a timeline so after visiting one city the animation will transition to be centered upon the next.

To my mind this means the [ViewVector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewVector.html) should be adjusted to show points between a starting city and an ending city. The resulting would probably look like an in-flight map for a long-haul flight sped up considerably. A single frame might look like the following manually produced still:

[image]

I now understand how to position the ViewVector above the most recent city but I am quite unsure about how to move the camera smoothly between two spherical coordinate points. My current code is below:

```
SC[{lat_, lon_}] := {Cos[lon \[Degree]] Cos[lat \[Degree]], 
   Sin[lon  \[Degree]] Cos[lat  \[Degree]], Sin[lat \[Degree]]};

GreatCircleArc[{lat1_, lon1_}, {lat2_, lon2_}] :=

 Module[{u = SC[{lat1, lon1}], v = SC[{lat2, lon2}], a}, 
  a = VectorAngle[u, v]; 
  Table[Evaluate[RotationTransform[\[Theta], {u, v}][u]], {\[Theta], 
0, a, a/Ceiling[10 a]}]]

CityGraphic[name_] := {Opacity[0.85], Black, PointSize[Medium], White,
   PointSize[0.045], Point[1.01 SC[CityData[name, "Coordinates"]]]}

CityGraph[places_, age_] := 
  Graphics3D[{
Opacity[0.75],
Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.99 ],
Map[Line[
   Map[SC,
    CountryData[#, "SchematicCoordinates"], {-2}]] &,
 CountryData["Countries"]],
Map[CityGraphic, places],
Text[Style[age, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 1.02 SC[CityData[First[places], "Coordinates"]]],
White, Line
 [Apply[GreatCircleArc, 
  Partition[Map[CityData[#, "Coordinates"] &, places], 2, 1], {1}]]
},
   ViewVector -> { 
 4 SC[CityData[First[places], "Coordinates"]], {0, 0, 0}},
   Boxed -> False,
   SphericalRegion -> True,
   ImageSize -> {640, 480}
   ];
CityGraph[{"Tokyo", "Dublin", "Cape Town", "Seattle", "Denver"}, "04"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In computer graphics people often use Quaternions to smoothly interpolate between various camera viewing directions. Mathematica has a [Quaternion package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Quaternions/tutorial/Quaternions.html) which you could use for basic Quaternion arithmetic. A conversion between Quaternions and Euler angles is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles).

The interpolation process is described [here](http://theory.org/software/qfa/writeup/node12.html).

Comment: +1. Interesting, never thought of that. For a point on a sphere, this must be related to the homomorphism from `SU(2)` to `SO(3)`.